How would I change my php to update all of the fields in the page, instead of using a button for each row?
I have an in-house app I use to query the database by PO number and then insert all of the data into a separate table called label_print. Our label software is connected to this database.
One of the options on the web page is to change the quantity of labels to be printed for each product line. It displays a tabulated page with text fields holding the current value from the database. I'm using a foreach loop for the form data, including a submit button. As a result, there is a button next to each record so that I can change the quantity. I would like to change it so that I can just press one update button on the bottom of the page and have it save all of the rows of data.
I've tried several suggestions from copilot, stackoverflow, and google, but I can't seem to find this particular scenario (which is surprising because this seems like a common need). I tried using form fields with arrays[] and running a loop on the pdo structure, but I feel like I'm dancing in circles for something that is probably really easy once you know how to do it.
Here's my current php and html that I would like to switch over to single-button-save.
**PHP Code
**
    $sql_labels = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM label_print");
    $sql_labels->execute();
    $result = $sql_labels->fetchAll();

    if(isset($_POST['update-qty'])){

    $qty = $_POST['quantity'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    
    $sql_updated_qty = $conn->prepare("UPDATE label_print SET quantity = :qty WHERE id = :id");
    $sql_updated_qty->bindParam(':qty', $qty, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql_updated_qty->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql_updated_qty->execute();


**HTML code
**
    <table class="table hover">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>UPC</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>quantity</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach($result as $row) { ?>
                            <form action='' method="POST">
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row["upc"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row["description"]; ?></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $row['quantity']; ?>" class="form-control mt-2"></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" name="update-qty" id="update-qty" value="Update Qty" class="form-control btn btn-secondary mt-2"></td>
                            <td><input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                             </form>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

I tried using the following code for the php without any luck.

        $sql_labels = $conn->prepare("UPDATE labels_print SET quantity = :quantity WHERE id = :id");

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($id); $i++) {
            $sql_labels->execute([
                ':id' => $id[$i],
                ':quantity' => $qty[$i]
            ]);
        }


HTML
                        <?php foreach($result as $row) { ?>
                            <form name="form1" action='' method="POST">
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row["upc"]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row["description"]; ?></td>
                            <td><input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity[]" value="<?php echo $row['quantity']; ?>" class="form-control mt-2"></td>
                            <td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" id="id" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"></td>
                        </tr>
                             </form>
                        <?php } ?>
                             <table><tr><td><input type="submit" form="form1" name="update-qty" id="update-qty" value="Update Qty" class="form-control btn btn-secondary mt-2"></td>


What have you tried so far and what are you stuck with?

Your HTML is invalid - you have a form located within the table but it should either be in a single table-cell or the entire table should be within the form. You cannot nest the form like you have above

I see you tried using array style naming convention for the form elements - that is the way to proceed

You cannot assign the form elements duplicate IDs and for what you are trying to do here you simply don't need IDs anyway
